# How to Submit URLs to Googlebot without verifying In Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, googlebot, search-engine-bots

Is there a way or api to register Url on Google? For example, when a page was created in the project, its address will be automatically submit to [Googlebot](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en&mesd=AB9YKzI7FCb8LGTX7HA_M05yT-BvbOScWFB-xXKkJCJ-MVlmPc7JI5LJjSMYVCwCG5t3y1VwWIOE_5APFVeIOjoOJVeqLmqgS93MC24AXuOOmaVCqVYyqkCd7Cl_2SAyfrzrBd3tIysv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a way to submit it automatically (otherwise there would be no captcha).

However why do you want to submit every page to GoogleBot? It is sufficient to point the bot to your project's address once the project goes online (if Google didn't already found your project). GoogleBot is regularly visiting your project, automatically adding/removing new and old pages in your project (as soon as there is somewhere in your project a link pointing to the new page).

Comment: There is a limit to indexing the number of pages. For example, our site has about 80,000 pages, but about 6000 is indexed and no longer knows the pages. And this is a long process.